# Using built-in camcorder microphone with Skype on OS X

Tags: macos, skype, camera, microphone, firewire

I have a MacMini.  I want to use it for video calling with Skype.  Rather than buying a new webcam I have managed to set-up my Sony Handycam as a webcam by connecting it to the Mac with a Firewire cable.  So far so good but I would also like to use the camera's built-in microphone for the call.  The reason for this is because the MacMini's 3.5mm microphone jack does not work with normal cheap unpowered microphones like those that you might use in a similar port on a PC.  So while I can make calls without a problem on my old Windows laptop, I would need to buy a USB or Bluetooth microphone/headset to get it to work on the Mac.

When I use the Handycam on my Windows PC (connected via USB rather than Firewire), Skype prompts me to ask whether I would also like to use the camera's microphone.  I don't get this prompt with Firewire on OS X and the USB connection does not seem to work with the Mac.

Does anybody know whether it is possible (and how) to get Skype to capture the audio over Firewire on OS X, or to get OS X to recognise the Handycam when attached via USB?  Currently the camera does not appear in the list of possible audio inputs in the Skype preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this page](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=87597) I have figured out how to get the audio to work as well as the video.  While USB streaming doesn't work and Firewire only provides pictures, if you connect the camera to the Mac using both Firewire *and* USB cables, the camera's microphone will be available in the Skype preferences as "Unknown USB Audio Device".

Answer (score -1):

Also, for those using a DV camcorder that only has a firewire port (no USB option) you can use the A/V out port and the cable that came with your camcorder that goes from the A/V out port to RCA male. Then use an RCA female to line-in port on back of your Mac.